# Jmenu bar NullPoinerExpection

Tags: java, swing

I am having trouble on the jMeun bar and my code can compile but when i try to open it in display. The Null pointer Exception is appear. I don't know why it happens. The problem point out 3 lines that happen in my code. There are in the method of "createMenuBar"  frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);  and the last 2 line which is  frame.setSize(350, 250); frame.setVisible(true);

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class Game extends JFrame {
    private JFrame frame;
    JButton[][] grids = new JButton[9][9];


    public Game() {
        createGrids();

    }

    private void quit()
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void createGrids(){
        frame = new JFrame("game");
        createMenuBar(frame);;
        setTitle("game");
        JPanel m = new JPanel(new GridLayout(9,9));
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                grids[i][j] = new JButton();
                m.add(grids[i][j]);
            }
        }
        add(m, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        m = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));

        add(m, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        setSize(200, 240);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createMenuBar(JFrame frame)
    {
        final int SHORTCUT_MASK =
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask();

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        JMenu menu;
        JMenuItem item;

        menu = new JMenu("Option");
        menuBar.add(menu);

        item = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        item.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O, SHORTCUT_MASK));
        item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { quit(); }
            });
        menu.add(item);

        frame.setSize(350, 250);
        frame.setVisible(true);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look at ...

```
createMenuBar(frame);
frame = new JFrame("game");
```

When you pass `frame` to `createMenuBar` it is `null`...

You're also extending your class from `JFrame`, but also declaring a instance field of type `JFrame`, this is very confusing and unnecessary.  Get rid of the `extends JFrame`, it will make your life easier...

Also, you need to learn how to read a stack trace, it's providing all the information you really need.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test1.Test1.createMenuBar(Test1.java:61)
    at test1.Test1.createGrids(Test1.java:36)
    at test1.Test1.<init>(Test1.java:27)
    at test1.Test1.main(Test1.java:23)
```

- `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException` is telling you "what" has gone wrong...
- `at test1.Test1.createMenuBar(Test1.java:61)` is telling you where it's going wrong (or as close as it can)
- The remaining entries is giving you the trace through you code to the problem, from `test1.Test1.main(Test1.java:23)` to `test1.Test1.createGrids(Test1.java:36)`

The trace provides you with `package.class.method(File:line number)` information, this is very helpful for tracing through your code to see where the problem actually came from and what might have lead up to it

[image: Viola]

Comment: OMG ! Thankyou very much. Just compile it but my MenuBar did not come up do you know why?

Comment: It's because you actually have two `JFrame`s, the class is extending from `JFrame` and you are creating a second `JFrame`, the second instance is been configured, but the class is been shown.  Get rid of `extends JFrame` and fix the errors by using `frame` instead...

Comment: Thank you very much! I have changed it to frame. and my code works ! Also, I have learnt so much I am really appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the object of JFrame to your method before creating the JFrame object.

```
createMenuBar(frame);
frame = new JFrame("game");
```

It should be:

```
frame = new JFrame("game");
createMenuBar(frame);
```

**Edit**

1. You have called `frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);` method even before adding components to your JMenu Bar. It means when you set JMenuBar to your frame, JMenuBar doesn't have any menus.
2. First you are extending your class from `JFrame` so it itself becomes a JFrame then you have created a new JFrame object in your method `createGrids()` and then you pass this object to your second method `createMenuBar(frame)`.

   As Java is pass by value, it simply means the object of JFrame which you created in your method `createGrids()` is copied to the `argument frame` and then you add your JMenuBar to this *third* JFrame, which you don't display.

Comment: Oh no wonder !!!! Thank you ! It compiles but my menuBar did not come up do you know why?

Comment: *"You have called frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar); method even before adding components to your JMenu Bar. It means when you set JMenuBar to your frame, JMenuBar doesn't have any menus."* but the OP adds menu items to the `menuBar` after it...doubt that's the issue

Comment: Thankyou ! I have added frame. to the code to make it work Thank you !

Comment: @GPRathour You newly added second point is the cause of the problem.  Adding menu items to a `JMenuBar` after it's been added to a frame would not cause it to not be visible...

Answer (score 0):

You have extended your `Game` Class with `JFrame`.

Then you have created a member variable `private JFrame frame;`

When you have already extended the Game class, you do not need the member variable. Just remove all references to the member `frame` and you should be all set.

For example:

1. In `createMenuBar(JFrame frame)` method, remove the parameter `JFrame frame`.
2. Change `frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar)` to `this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);`
3. Then in the last two lines change `frame.` to `this.`.
4. Inside `createGrids()` method, simply call `createMenuBar();`
5. Remove `frame = new JFrame("game");`

The following code should work:

```
    public class Game extends JFrame {
        JButton[][] grids = new JButton[9][9];

        public Game() {
            createGrids();

        }

        private void quit()
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        public void createGrids(){
            createMenuBar();
            setTitle("game");
            JPanel m = new JPanel(new GridLayout(9,9));
            for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                    grids[i][j] = new JButton();
                    m.add(grids[i][j]);
                }
            }
            add(m, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            m = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));

            add(m, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            setSize(200, 240);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
        }

        private void createMenuBar()
        {
            final int SHORTCUT_MASK =
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask();

            JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
            JMenu menu;
            JMenuItem item;

            menu = new JMenu("Option");
            menuBar.add(menu);

            item = new JMenuItem("Quit");
            item.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O, SHORTCUT_MASK));
            item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { quit(); }
                });
            menu.add(item);

            setJMenuBar(menuBar);

            setSize(350, 250);
            setVisible(true);  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Generally speaking, it's not recommended to extend directly from a top level container like `JFrame`, you're locking yourself into a single use case and aren't really adding any new (re-usable) functionality of the class - just saying ;)

Comment: I agree @MadProgrammer, I'd rather extend JPanels. But I was focusing more on making the code work.

Comment: True, but you could have dropped the `extends JFrame` and focused on maintaining the instance field, just saying ;)